# Line color between cells in selected row (TableView)

Tags: css, javafx

I set the color of the selected row using css (JavaFX):

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray ;
}
```

I also set the color of some other rows using css pseudo classes:

```
.table-row-cell:redRow {
    -fx-background-color: orangered ;
}
.table-row-cell:aquaRow {
    -fx-background-color: aqua ;
}
```

The result is shown in the picture:

[image]

For **unselected** rows, the vertical lines between cells are white.

The problem is that the **selected** row has vertical lines that still blue.
How to change the color of these vertical lines to white ? (so that the filled rows differ only in the background color)

P.S. Selected row in the picture is gray

---

Here is a simpler working example of an application with a similar result:

*Main class:*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            ObservableList<PrimitiveModel> variableList = FXCollections.<PrimitiveModel>observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                variableList.add(new PrimitiveModel(i, i*2.5, Integer.toString(i*3)));
            }

            TableView<PrimitiveModel> myTable = new TableView<PrimitiveModel>(variableList);
            myTable.getColumns().addAll(getIntegerColumn(), getDoubleColumn(), getStringColumn());
            myTable.setPrefSize(400.0, 300.0);


            PseudoClass redRowPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("redRow");
            PseudoClass aquaRowPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("aquaRow");

            myTable.setRowFactory( table ->{  
                TableRow<PrimitiveModel> row = new TableRow<>();

                row.itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<PrimitiveModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends PrimitiveModel> observable, PrimitiveModel oldValue,
                            PrimitiveModel newValue) {
                        if(oldValue!=null) {
                            if(oldValue.getInteger()%2==0) {
                                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(redRowPseudoClass, false);
                            }else {
                                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(aquaRowPseudoClass, false);
                            }
                        }

                        if(newValue!=null) {
                            if(newValue.getInteger()%2==0) {
                                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(redRowPseudoClass, true);
                            }else {
                                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(aquaRowPseudoClass, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                row.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                        if(row.getItem()!=null) {
                            if (newValue) {
                                if(row.getItem().getInteger()%2==0) {
                                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(redRowPseudoClass, false);
                                }else {
                                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(aquaRowPseudoClass, false);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if(row.getItem().getInteger()%2==0) {
                                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(redRowPseudoClass, true);
                                }else {
                                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(aquaRowPseudoClass, true);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
                return row;
            });

            VBox root = new VBox(myTable);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("TableStyle.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, Integer> getIntegerColumn() {
        TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, Integer> integerCol = new TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, Integer>("Integer");
        integerCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PrimitiveModel, Integer>("integer")); 
        return integerCol;
    }

    public static TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, Double> getDoubleColumn() {
        TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, Double> doubleCol = new TableColumn<>("Double");
        doubleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PrimitiveModel, Double>("double"));
        return doubleCol;
    }

    public static TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, String> getStringColumn() {
        TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, String> stringCol = new TableColumn<PrimitiveModel, String>("String");
        stringCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PrimitiveModel, String>("string")); 
        return stringCol;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*Model class:*

```
public class PrimitiveModel {

    public PrimitiveModel(int i, double d, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.d = d;
        this.s = s;
    }
    public int getInteger() {
        return i;
    }
    public double getDouble() {
        return d;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return s;
    }

    private int i;
    private double d;
    private String s;
}
```

*TableStyle.css* file:

```
.table-row-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: lightgray ;
}


.table-row-cell:redRow {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}


.table-row-cell:aquaRow {
    -fx-background-color: aqua ;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which provided that output?

Comment: @ManojKumar Added a simpler example

Comment: Thanks but can you make the code run in an environment so that some of us can look into it through DevTools.

Comment: @ManojKumar This code is working. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/ to create a working demo of the code.

Comment: I suspect that the vertical line is the border of the table-cell - looking at the modena theme, they are derived from the content background. You probably need to make the cells aware of the custom pseudo-classes and add border styles for them

Comment: @ManojKumar the code _is_ working, just throw it into your favorite IDE :)

Comment: hmm ... my assumption probably is wrong, couldn't verify it ..

Comment: Don't forget to fix the `-fx-control-inner-background-alt` value as well...

Comment: @trilogy .. that's too high for me, I always leave the styling to others :) For OP could verify that the blueish line is the left cell-border by changing it to white (clumsiness ahead <g>)    `.table-cell:filled:even {
   -fx-border-color: #00000000 white #00000000 #00000000;
} 
`  ... there are more to adjust, but this could be a starter

Comment: besides the modena.css, scenicview is a good tool to check the actual values (some can be even changed to see the effects)

Comment: @kleopatra You are right, border of the table-cell can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-right, border-left for the **td** tag. so it will only apply for vertical lines.

check the below snippet

```
  td {
    border-right: solid 1px lightgray; 
    border-left: solid 1px lightgray;
  }
```

Comment: I checked and it looks like it is not working. I get a warning <Unknown property: "border-left">. Are you sure that this should work in JavaFX?

Comment: Added a simpler example

Comment: this is javafx, not html :)

Comment: though: the borders seems to be handled similarly, it is the left of a table-cell that defines the "line" between columns :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best solution (add this style to .css file):

```
.table-cell{
    -fx-border-color: #ececec;  /* similar to the default color */
    -fx-border-width: 0.5;   /* similar to the default width */
}
```

*Border-color* determines the color of lines between cells.

This css style applies to all TableView, not only selected row. But it works: blue lines no longer appear.

One of the disadvantage is that you need to specify the *border-width* of the line, otherwise the arrangement of some cells is shifted.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game perhaps, but here's the best solution:

Modena.css has the following for TableView cells:

```
/* Selected rows */
.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected,
.tree-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-cell:filled:selected,
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.tree-table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell .table-cell:selected,
.tree-table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-table-row-cell .tree-table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%);
}
```

As you can see, the background colour is `-fx-selection-bar` which is the blue colour via `-fx-accent`.

So, you can adjust this by simply changing the colour of `-fx-selection-bar` in the context of your style class, like so:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
  -fx-background-color: lightgray ;
  -fx-selection-bar: lightgray;
}
```

And the blue lines go away.